# Conditions for a space curve to have constant torsion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame

> Prove that a regular curve $\alpha$, with non vanishing curvature, has constant torsion $\tau = \cfrac{1}{a}, a \neq 0$ if, and only if: $$\alpha(t) = a\left( \int f_1(t) \ dt,\int f_2(t) \ dt, \int f_3(t) \ dt \right)$$
>
> where $(f_1, f_2,f_3) = F \times F'$ and $F$ is a vector valued function such that $||F(t)|| = 1$ and $F \cdot(F' \times F'') \neq 0$.

I don't know how to start solving this. My only idea was to try solving the differential equations of the TNB frame, but I have too little information. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to solve them just read them. The condition you give is that 
$$\alpha^{\prime}(t)=aF\times F^{\prime}$$ So you just need to identify $F$. And if you assume that $\alpha$ is parameterized by arc length, $\mathbf{t}=\alpha^{\prime}$. And it seems that $F=\mathbf{b}$. I leave the rest of the verification up to you.

Comment: How do I identify $F$? I'm tempted to assume $F = B(t)$, the binormal vector, but I don't know how to ground that assumption, and even then, it does not seem clear to me how to proceed.

Comment: Well I guess that part of the process of learning math.

Comment: It is. Could you help me on that? I'm guessing it probably looks obvious to you, but it doesn't to me.